# Setting the order of TYPO3 BE module

Tags: typo3, extbase

I registered successfully a BE module and submodule in Extbase extension with this common code and of course it works:

```
/** Myext modules group */
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerModule($_EXTKEY, 'myext', '', ''
    ,array(),
    array(
        'icon' => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY .'/ext_icon.gif',
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_myext.xml',
   )
);

/** Myext items list mod */
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerModule($_EXTKEY, 'myext', 'itemslist','',
    array('Item' => 'list',),
    array(
        'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Icons/mod_items.gif',
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_myext_items.xml',
    )
);
```

My problem is that I can't change its ordering in anyway, it always displays at the end of the left column (after **Help** section). The 4-th param of `registerModule` method is position anyway apparently it doesn't affect the main module, only submodules.

So how can I place Myext right after the `web`? in such case?

I'm working on TYPO3 ver.: `4.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I missunderstood you. You mean your own category that you want to set a specified position.

There is no official way but you can manual reset the order with following code:

```php
// add module before 'File'
if (!isset($TBE_MODULES['yourExtensionCategory']))  {
    $temp_TBE_MODULES = array();
    foreach($TBE_MODULES as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == 'file') {
            $temp_TBE_MODULES['yourExtensionCategory'] = '';
            $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
        } else {
            $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    $TBE_MODULES = $temp_TBE_MODULES;
}
```

Comment: That exactly what I did basing on DAM code :) Anyway, thank you for confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will set the module link to a specified position:

```php
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerModule(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'web', // Make module a submodule of 'web'
    'yourmodulem1', // Submodule key
    'before:web_ViewpageView', // Position
    array(
        'Controller' => 'action1, action2'
    ),
    array(
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'icon' => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Icons/icon.png',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_m1.xml',
    )
);
```

You have set the second argument "mainModuleName" wrong, it is the category, your module belongs to. Valid values are `web, files, user, tools, help`. The fourth argument "position" can have following values `after:module_id`, `before:module_id` or `top`. Empty mean `bottom` and is default. To get the id of the module, simply inspect the link-element of the menu with your favourite web-developer-tool, the attribute `id=` descripes the module_id.

Heres the documentation of `registerModule`:

```php
/**
 * Registers an Extbase module (main or sub) to the backend interface.
 * FOR USE IN ext_tables.php FILES
 *
 * @param string $extensionName The extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore)
 * @param string $mainModuleName The main module key, $sub is the submodule key. So $main would be an index in the $TBE_MODULES array and $sub could be an element in the lists there. If $main is not set a blank $extensionName module is created
 * @param string $subModuleName The submodule key. If $sub is not set a blank $main module is created
 * @param string $position This can be used to set the position of the $sub module within the list of existing submodules for the main module. $position has this syntax: [cmd]:[submodule-key]. cmd can be "after", "before" or "top" (or blank which is default). If "after"/"before" then submodule will be inserted after/before the existing submodule with [submodule-key] if found. If not found, the bottom of list. If "top" the module is inserted in the top of the submodule list.
 * @param array $controllerActions is an array of allowed combinations of controller and action stored in an array (controller name as key and a comma separated list of action names as value, the first controller and its first action is chosen as default)
 * @param array $moduleConfiguration The configuration options of the module (icon, locallang.xml file)
 * @return void
 */
```

Please note: if you have templavoila installed, the "page"-Module has not the id "page", it is   "web_txtemplavoilaM1", because templavoila replaces the whole page module.